# Typescript - With Array<T>, how to dynamically determine and create new instance of T?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have a bunch of typed Arrays of different objects. I want to write a function that adds a new blank object to the array that will work with any array as long as the type has an empty constructor.

I'm new to Angular 2 and Typescript. The arrays are part of a form and I want to be able to add a new row/object, however I have many arrays and would appreciate a generic function for all of them.

```
someObject {
    constructor() { this.someField = ""; ... }
    someField: string;
    ...

}

someOtherObject {
    constructor() { this.someOtherField = ""; ... }
    someOtherField: string;
    ...
}

Array<someObject> someArray = someObject[{...}, {...} ...];
Array<someOtherObject> someOtherArray = someOtherObject[{...}, {...} ...];


// What I would like, that would work with either above array
// new T() obviously doesn't work however

addRow<T>(array:Array<T>) : void {
    array.push(new T());
}
```

There is *instanceOf* to determine whether an object is some class. However, I haven't found a way to access the type as an object of an Array.

I can probably use the code below BUT sometimes the array may be empty and this won't work - however it will still be typed to  so in theory we should still be able to create it.

```
if(array.length > 0 && array[0] instanceOf(someObject)) { 
    array.push(new someObject()); 
} 
// else if instance of someOtherObject... so on so forth
```

Is there a better way of achieving what I want, or a method I'm unaware of? Thank you.

**EDIT:** As Alexander said, you can dynamically do this in Typescript by using

```
addRow<T>(array:Array<T>, c: {new(): T}) : void {
    array.push(new c());
}

addRow(someArray, someObject);
addRow(someOtherArray, someOtherObject);
```

*This doesn't work when used in the HTML*
e.g. `<div class="btn btn-default" (click)="addRow(someArray, someObject)"></div>` **won't work** as the HTML doesn't know about the someObject class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html (see "Using Class Types in Generics") the best you can do is this:

```
class someObject {
    constructor() { this.someField = ""; }
    someField: string;
}

class someOtherObject {
    constructor() { this.someOtherField = ""; }
    someOtherField: string;
}

var someArray: Array<someObject> = [];
var someOtherArray: Array<someOtherObject> = [];

function addRow<T>(array: Array<T>, c: {new(): T}) : void {
    array.push(new c());
}

addRow(someArray, someObject);
addRow(someOtherArray, someOtherObject);
```

It is due to the fact that you must pass constructor function as a parameter in order to be able to create an instance of it. Generic declarations are only for compiler to perform type checks and does not produce real code while passing constructor function does.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried using the above but I get the following error

    `TypeError: c is not a constructor`

Comment: @Helen, what typescript version do you use? It works for me on 2.0.10.

Comment: 2.0.10, Google said some older versions had a bug which gave this error message, but unless that was reintroduced that doesn't seem to be the case. To confirm, I've got the call in my html as `(click)="addRow(data.array)"`

Comment: @Helen, even if it is in an html you still need to pass constructor as a second parameter, but I'm not sure how angular compiler will look at it. I'd say that it's better to wrap such a call into another method with no parameters at all and call this wrapper from html. Besides, you didn't mention it in your question. ;)

Comment: You're right, when I try pass `someObject.constructor()` into the function Angular doesn't recognise it. It works if I wrap it like you suggested, or call it just in Typescript. 

Unfortunately, for my case this means I can't dynamically generate the object as I need to know which constructor to use and that information is in the html. My bad for not mentioning that in the question, I assumed it wouldn't matter (woops). I'll just make a separate function for each object type. Thanks so much for your help Alexander!

Comment: @Helen, you shouldn't try someObject.constructor() since it is calling function constructor() on someObject and passing its result further. Constructor function (this is more javascript term) is a class itself (typescript), so what you should be passing is just someObject anyway, but as you say it does not work in html template... so be it. :)